# Making a plot half the width and height of another plot?

Tags: plotting, graphics

I have the following plot:

```
P1=Plot[1000*Exp[-0.03*t],{t,0,100},Frame->True]
```

Is there a simple way to make another plot whose frame is is half the width and height of plot P1?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Is there a simple way to make another plot whose frame is is half the
> width and height of plot P1?

I do not know if I understood the question correctly. If not, will delete this. But how about using the `ImageSize` for this?

```
P1 = Plot[1000*Exp[-0.03*t], {t, 0, 100}, Frame -> True, ImageSize -> {300, 300}];

P2 = Plot[1000*Exp[-0.03*t], {t, 0, 100}, Frame -> True, ImageSize -> {150, 150}];

Grid[{{P1, P2}}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

> Do you know what size "Large" represents,

I could not find from help this information. It just says "predefined". It might be possible to find this out by making a `Large` size image, then search the internals of the Plot structure looking for the actual size.

But a quick test shows it is around `560` but it can depend on other factors.

```
Manipulate[Module[{P1, P2},
  P1 = Plot[1000*Exp[-0.03*t], {t, 0, 100}, Frame -> True, 
    ImageSize -> {p, p}];
  P2 = Plot[1000*Exp[-0.03*t], {t, 0, 100}, Frame -> True, 
    ImageSize -> Large];
  Grid[{{P1, P2}}, Spacings -> {10, 5}]
  ],
 {{p, 300, "size?"}, 100, 1000, 10, Appearance -> "Labeled"},
 TrackedSymbols :> {p}
 ]
```

Move the slider until the images are "same" size. This tells what `Large` is

[image: Mathematica graphics]

`560` gives

[image: Mathematica graphics]

You can see what options Mathematica used by doing

```
p = Plot[1000*Exp[-0.03*t], {t, 0, 100}, Frame -> True, ImageSize -> Large]
AbsoluteOptions[p]
```

This shows that in this case `Large` used

```
  ImageSize -> {576., 354.747},
```

So the Manipulate inspection method was close. I do not know how Mathematica decides what `Large` is. I am sure there are lots of heuristics involved.

Comment: I will try this now, thank you! Right now the actual plot I am using has a size of ImageSize -> Automatic -> Large. Do you know what size "Large" represents, e.g., is it somewhere near {300, 300}?

Comment: @tardigrade good question. I searched help and could not find what `Large` size is, But added a way to found out.